# How to set Page footer to the bottom of the every page in Jasper Reports?

Tags: jasper-reports

> For export the **page footer** are always at the bottom of the page.

**But in Print preview the page footer comes immediately after the detail band.**

I want the **page footer** to appear always at the bottom of the page , irrespective of detail band height.

Below is the xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.0.3.final using JasperReports Library version 6.0.3  -->
<!-- 2015-03-12T14:09:48 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd"
name="Listing Report" pageWidth="1385" pageHeight="922" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="1335" leftMargin="25" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
  <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5" />
  <property name="ireport.x" value="0" />
  <property name="ireport.y" value="0" />
  <template>
    <![CDATA[$P{templatePath}]]>
  </template>
  <style name="Crosstab Data Text" />
  <style name="Zebra" mode="Opaque">
    <conditionalStyle> <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V {
      REPORT_COUNT
    }
    %2==1]]></conditionExpression> <style backcolor="#F0F0F0"/> </conditionalStyle>
  </style>
  <parameter name="appointmentid" class="java.lang.String" />
  <parameter name="reportsetid" class="java.lang.Object" />
  <parameter name="savedreportid" class="java.lang.Object" />
  <parameter name="dbtablename" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription>
      <![CDATA[appointmentlistingseedreport]]>
    </parameterDescription>
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="partialInlineQuery" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription>
     <!-----------------Query--------------------->
    </parameterDescription>
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="dynamicdbtablename" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
    <parameterDescription>
      <![CDATA[appointmentlistingdynamicdata]]>
    </parameterDescription>
  </parameter>
  <parameter name="templatePath" class="java.lang.String" />
  <queryString>
    <!--Query String------------------>
  </queryString>
  <field name="reportsetid" class="java.lang.Object" />
  <field name="savedreportid" class="java.lang.Object" />
  <field name="organizationname" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="duration" class="java.lang.Integer" />
  <field name="appointmenttypename" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="personname" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="appointmentstatus" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="appointmentdate" class="java.sql.Date" />
  <field name="location" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="ordername" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="ordertype" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="orderstatus" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="resultstatus" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="resourcename" class="java.lang.String" />
  <field name="appointmentstarttime" class="java.sql.Time" />
  <variable name="GrandTotal_Count" class="java.math.BigDecimal" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA[$F{reportsetid}]]>
    </variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <variable name="GrandTotal_Variable" class="java.lang.String" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA["Grand Total ( " +  $V{GrandTotal_Count} + ")"]]>
    </variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <variable name="organizationname_Count" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="organizationname" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA[$F{organizationname}]]>
    </variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <variable name="organizationname_Variable" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="organizationname" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA["Total for " + (($F{organizationname} != null) ?   $F{organizationname} : "") + " " + "(" + $V{organizationname_Count} + ")"]]>
    </variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <variable name="location_Count" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="location" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA[$F{location}]]>
    </variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <variable name="location_Variable" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="location" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA["Total for " + (($F{location} != null) ?   $F{location} : "") + " " + "(" + $V{location_Count} + ")"]]>
    </variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <variable name="resourcename_Count" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Group" resetGroup="resourcename" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA[$F{resourcename}]]>
    </variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <variable name="resourcename_Variable" class="java.lang.String" resetType="Group" resetGroup="resourcename" calculation="Count">
    <variableExpression>
      <![CDATA["Total for " + (($F{resourcename} != null) ?   $F{resourcename} : "") + " " + "(" + $V{resourcename_Count} + ")"]]>
    </variableExpression>
  </variable>
  <group name="FooterGrandTotal">
    <groupFooter>
      <band height="20">
        <textField>
          <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="20" uuid="a23e46f3-b798-42ec-816e-c3e0c76ee7f6" />
          <textElement>
            <font size="17" isBold="true" />
          </textElement>
          <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA[(($V{GrandTotal_Variable} != null) ?   $V{GrandTotal_Variable} : "")]]>
          </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
    </groupFooter>
  </group>
  <group name="organizationname" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression>
      <![CDATA[(($F{organizationname} != null) ?   ($F{organizationname} +"   "+     "<style isItalic='true' forecolor='#aaaaaa'>Org</style> ") :"Org")]]>
    </groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
      <band height="20">
        <textField>
          <reportElement style="Zebra" x="0" y="0" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="cf936d24-cfb0-44ff-a601-e4bcba0a1cf7" />
          <box leftPadding="15" />
          <textElement markup="styled">
            <font size="17" isBold="true" />
          </textElement>
          <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA[(($F{organizationname} != null) ?   ($F{organizationname} +"   "+     "<style isItalic='true' forecolor='#aaaaaa'>Org</style> ") :"Org")]]>
          </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
      <band height="20">
        <textField>
          <reportElement style="Zebra" x="0" y="0" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="cf936d24-cfb0-44ff-a601-e4bcba0a1cf7" />
          <box leftPadding="15" />
          <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font size="17" isBold="true" />
          </textElement>
          <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA[(($V{organizationname_Variable} != null) ?   $V{organizationname_Variable} : "")]]>
          </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
    </groupFooter>
  </group>
  <group name="location">
    <groupExpression>
      <![CDATA[(($F{location} != null) ?   ($F{location} +"   "+     "<style isItalic='true' forecolor='#aaaaaa'>Location</style> ") :"Location")]]>
    </groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
      <band height="20">
        <textField>
          <reportElement style="Zebra" x="0" y="0" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="0f1dc658-577b-4a1a-a937-b21af77454d4" />
          <box leftPadding="40" />
          <textElement markup="styled">
            <font size="17" isBold="true" />
          </textElement>
          <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA[(($F{location} != null) ?   ($F{location} +"   "+     "<style isItalic='true' forecolor='#aaaaaa'>Location</style> ") :"Location")]]>
          </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
      <band height="20">
        <textField>
          <reportElement style="Zebra" x="0" y="0" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="0f1dc658-577b-4a1a-a937-b21af77454d4" />
          <box leftPadding="40" />
          <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font size="17" isBold="true" />
          </textElement>
          <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA[(($V{location_Variable} != null) ?   $V{location_Variable} : "")]]>
          </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
    </groupFooter>
  </group>
  <group name="resourcename">
    <groupExpression>
      <![CDATA[(($F{resourcename} != null) ?   ($F{resourcename} +"   "+     "<style isItalic='true' forecolor='#aaaaaa'>Resource</style> ") :"Resource")]]>
    </groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
      <band height="20">
        <textField>
          <reportElement style="Zebra" x="0" y="0" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#333333"/>
          <box leftPadding="65" />
          <textElement markup="styled">
            <font size="17" isBold="true" />
          </textElement>
          <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA[(($F{resourcename} != null) ?   ($F{resourcename} +"   "+     "<style isItalic='true' forecolor='#aaaaaa'>Resource</style> ") :"Resource")]]>
          </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
      <band height="20">
        <textField>
          <reportElement style="Zebra" x="0" y="0" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="613e4649-a0be-402b-b641-6792d681a3fd" />
          <box leftPadding="65" />
          <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
            <font size="17" isBold="true" />
          </textElement>
          <textFieldExpression>
            <![CDATA[(($V{resourcename_Variable} != null) ?   $V{resourcename_Variable} : "")]]>
          </textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
      </band>
    </groupFooter>
  </group>
  <title>
    <band height="24" splitType="Stretch" />
  </title>
  <pageHeader>
    <band height="100">
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#999999" uuid="07f143b8-4615-48bf-a984-3f5d9f1b7fdb" />
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(("GENHEALTH FAMILY PRACTICE ASSOCIATES (GFPA)" != null) ?   "GENHEALTH FAMILY PRACTICE ASSOCIATES (GFPA)" : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#999999" uuid="548c383a-181b-4a5e-9773-95bec6028b2f" />
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" isItalic="true" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(("Appointment List" != null) ?   "Appointment List" : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="0" y="40" width="1335" height="20" forecolor="#999999" uuid="9a238441-512f-4e24-84c4-d0c6f78a912a" />
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(("Appointment Date : is not : 03/12/2015" != null) ?   "Appointment Date : is not : 03/12/2015" : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
    </band>
  </pageHeader>
  <columnHeader>
    <band height="25" splitType="Stretch">
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="0" y="0" width="210" height="20" uuid="2d0b156b-95f8-487c-bb7d-09e729e3e364">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <box leftPadding="85" />
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Appt Type]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="210" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="e059ad06-5f5d-4056-9217-a21fa154640e">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Appt Date]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="335" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="3890f6d6-0d75-4bda-90ca-97cb7a7d4333">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Appt Time]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="460" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="9f7d46ea-c2ee-4a6f-ba73-57e90ed1045b">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Appt Dur]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="585" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="e4d430ab-b03d-4f18-8779-c8d37e30e21b">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Pat Name]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="710" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="3c06f694-8e55-4565-af1a-7386ccee9422">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Appt Sts]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="835" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="434fe607-d680-4fef-b67d-0cc18957f6f9">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Order Name]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="960" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="a2f59de7-7964-4d52-8beb-e9f4e3c8ca03">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Order Type]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="1085" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="4b7703eb-2426-4574-bb23-66b35dadaa03">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Order Status]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
      <staticText>
        <reportElement style="table-header" x="1210" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="1add3ebc-c688-41af-831c-efba8ee67b92">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Result Status]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </columnHeader>
  <detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="0" y="0" width="210" height="20" uuid="2ae4a4f2-473e-42a9-8055-c02309813c9a">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <box leftPadding="85" />
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(($F{appointmenttypename} != null) ?   $F{appointmenttypename} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="210" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="d9a4e371-73f3-4540-a135-952dacb1d937">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.formatDate($F{appointmentdate})]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="335" y="0" width="125" height="20" uuid="b293699a-e8cb-4dd4-a878-1fc5082f686d">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[$P{REPORT_SCRIPTLET}.formatTime($F{appointmentstarttime})]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="460" y="0" width="125" height="20">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <box rightPadding="10" />
        <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
          <paragraph lineSpacing="1_1_2" rightIndent="20" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(($F{duration} != null) ?   $F{duration} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="585" y="0" width="125" height="20">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(($F{personname} != null) ?   $F{personname} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="710" y="0" width="125" height="20">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(($F{appointmentstatus} != null) ?   $F{appointmentstatus} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="835" y="0" width="125" height="20">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(($F{ordername} != null) ?   $F{ordername} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="960" y="0" width="125" height="20">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(($F{ordertype} != null) ?   $F{ordertype} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="1085" y="0" width="125" height="20">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(($F{orderstatus} != null) ?   $F{orderstatus} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement style="Zebra" x="1210" y="0" width="125" height="20">
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.at.char" value="true" />
          <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.text.truncate.suffix" value="..." />
        </reportElement>
        <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
          <font size="17" isBold="false" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(($F{resultstatus} != null) ?   $F{resultstatus} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
    </band>
  </detail>
  <pageFooter>
    <band height="100">
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="890" y="20" width="445" height="20"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Right">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(("Confidential" != null) ?   "Confidential" : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="445" height="20"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(("Prepared at 01:16 PM CDT,March 12, 2015" != null) ?   "Prepared at 01:16 PM CDT,March 12, 2015" : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField>
        <reportElement x="445" y="20" width="222" height="20"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Right">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[(("Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of" != null) ?   "Page "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" of" : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
      <textField evaluationTime="Report">
        <reportElement x="667" y="20" width="222" height="20"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
          <font size="17" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression>
          <![CDATA[((" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} != null) ?   " " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER} : "")]]>
        </textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
    </band>
  </pageFooter>
  <summary>
    <band height="35" splitType="Prevent" />
  </summary>
  <noData>
    <band height="20">
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="206" y="0" width="174" height="20"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Center">
          <font size="14" isBold="true" />
        </textElement>
        <text>
          <![CDATA[No Data Found]]>
        </text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </noData>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Which version are you using? The page footer should always appear at the bottom.

Comment: @brunobastosg : 6.0v

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its page footer? because page footer will always be at the bottom of page. Try decreasing the height, may be the top of your page footer is at middle of the page. And one more thing, page footer will always be after detail section unless you don't have a column footer in between.

Comment: Thank you for reply.

This happens only with print preview.There is no column footer. I reduced the page height and made page Footer appear in every page. but the page Footer is not fixed to the bottom of the page, it moves with the detail band content in every page.

Comment: But still just try this, set "Ignore pagination" property to true in your main report's properties.

Comment: Remove summary band and see, if it is working. Becasue you are not using it for anything.

Comment: Actually i am using it ... to display user selection.

Answer (score 0):

I just facing same issue, It seems that pageFooter extends its height to fill all left space if exists.

Try to change all your page footer elements position to "FixRelativeToBottom"

```
<reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" ... >
```

Or create a frame with this position type and then you put all your elements inside